# Linux module dependency

Tags: linux, ubuntu-10.04

We have a linux module developed by a 3rd party, now the module runs correctly on a Fedora system but on Ubuntu the same fails. When we do an ldd for the binary the following output is received

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf76f5000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf759b000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7705000)
        libutf16.so => not found
```

I am unable to find the library libutf16 for ubuntu, where can i find this library or is it part of a bigger library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [no file that contains `libutf16` in its name in any package in Ubuntu 10.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libutf16.so&mode=filename&suite=lucid&arch=any).